# Trying to randomly generate a binary number from 000 to 110

Tags: java, random, binary

I have code that randomly generates a binary number from 000 to 111 but I'm having trouble having it create a number from 000 to **just 110**. I know that I can somehow rerun the code everything it comes out with 111 but I can't seem to figure out the way to have it do that.

```
public String binNumber() {
        StringBuilder storage = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 3) {
            int binny = this.giveMeBinary();
            storage.append(String.valueOf(binny));

            i++;
        }


        return storage.toString();
    }

public int giveMeBinary() {
        Random rg = new Random();
        int bin = rg.nextInt(2);
        return bin;

    }
```

Comment: You are generating binary digits which appear to be the problem, try generating an integer number from 0 to 6 and then convert it to binary.

Answer (score 8):

The better way to do this is to generate a random number from 0 to 6 inclusive, and then convert to a string

```
public String binNumber() {
    Random rg = new Random();
    int n = rg.nextInt(7);
    return Integer.toBinaryString(n);
}
```

Comment: I think you mean the second line should take `7` as the argument.

Answer (score 3):

"Rerolling" if you get 111 is definitely a bad idea; that's potentially an algorithm with infinite running time, although in practice it would do quite well.

Why work in base 2? Work in base 10, easily get a random number between 0 and 6, and then translate back to binary.

Comment: Part of my project is to do it in binary.

Comment: I disagree that this is a bad idea.  The probability of rerolling is 1/8 on each iteration, so with probability 7/8 you will terminate on each iteration.  This gives an expected number of iterations of 8/7, with the probability of more iterations decreasing exponentially.  It would be an extremely rare event for this to require more than ten or so iterations, since that has probability 1/(8^10) = 1 / (2^30), which is about one in a billion.  The likelihood that this takes more than one hundred iterations is so low in the entire history of the universe it's unlikely to ever happen.

Comment: Like I said, "in practice it would do quite well." Surely you can agree that we should try to stay away from O(infinity) algorithms when there are sensible alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-roll, try this:

```
String num = "";
while (true)
{
      num = binNumber();
      if (!num.equals("111"))
      {
          break;
      }
}
return num;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Random random = new Random();

int nextNumber = random.nextInt( 7 );
System.out.println( Integer.toBinaryString( nextNumber ) );
```

Remember your numbers you create in a computer are always in binary.  You just need to print it out differently.  So even though you've given it a decimal number that number is converted by the compiler to binary. 7 == 0x111 when its compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I created a method which can return a random binary number below 128 (value 128 can be alter in the code)-

```
    public static void RandomBinary(int len){
    if(len<128) {
        Random random = new Random();
        boolean res;
        String randomBinary = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
            res = random.nextBoolean();
            if (res)
                randomBinary = randomBinary.concat("1");
            else
                randomBinary = randomBinary.concat("0");
        }
        System.out.print(randomBinary);
    }else {
        System.out.print("KeyGen maximum length allowed is 128. Please enter value below 128");
    }
}
```